# What is the java template engine/api for creating a text file?

Tags: java, templates, text-files

I want to create files in different formats in the java based web app. The files are pure text files without any html tags. But the files need a certain kind of format, text in left, middle, right or somewhere (tabs, spaces) in the file.

Template with the place holder + java bean with data = text file.

What java template engine or api is fit for this?

Thank you!

Comment: @mael, The template engine I am looking for is not for view but just a pure text file and it will be saved somewhere in the web application. Which one is best for the needs?

Comment: I have the same requirement now in 2019. Apart from String Template, can this be done in any better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check [String Template](http://www.stringtemplate.org) ([GitHub](http://www.stringtemplate.org)).

It looks like this:

```
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.*;

StringTemplate hello = new StringTemplate("Hello, $name$", DefaultTemplateLexer.class);
hello.setAttribute("name", "World");
System.out.println(hello.toString());
```

Comment: the String Template link results in "404: Page not found" error page.

Answer (score 2):

[Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html) is a pretty flexible templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of the following

- [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)
- Mustache template, an explanation [here](http://www.javarants.com/2010/06/16/building-the-ideal-web-application-template-engine/)

Answer (score 0):

For those who like clear separation there is an engine called [Snippetory](http://www.jproggy.org/snippetory). It completely separates logic form the textual part of the template, while providing rich feature set as expected from a mordern engine. It has some support for plain text formatting, can add additional formats as needed and makes up with a pluggable escaping facility. If the templates are small one can put several in one file, while being able to combine code from several files as well. And it's prety general, too.